# Table reformating

Tags: r, tidyr, kableextra

I have this table with two columns, major_activity_area and word_stem.

| major_activity_area | word_stem |
| --- | --- |
| Youth Development | program |
| Youth Development | girl |
| Youth Development | youth |
| Youth Development | school |
| Religion Related Spiritual Development | service |
| Religion Related Spiritual Development | provid |
| Religion Related Spiritual Development | program |
| Religion Related Spiritual Development | hous |

What I want to do is to make major_Activity_areas new columns and word_stem words to be listed under each columns. Such as:

| youth development. | Religion Related Spiritual Development |
| --- | --- |
| program. | servic |
| girl. | provid |
| youth | program |
| school | hous |

I would appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the str of data is tibble/ data frame, the function "pivot_wider" from tidyverse package would be a solution. I named your data as formal name (df) then calling the function. The code is like this :

```
library(tidyverse)


 dfw <-  pivot_wider( df, names_from = 
     'major_activity_area',values_from = 'word_stem') %>% unnest()

dfw
```